# tf2::ExtrapolationException, transforming point clouds from the past using a new transform

Tags: ros, time, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to put two pointclouds in a single frame that are taken from two different locations. The pointclouds are taken in the /base_link frame (which moves between scans), the position of the marker is determined, and a transform from /base_link to /marker is published. I then want to transform the pointcloud from /base_link to /marker, but the call:

```
listener->waitForTransform("/marker", (*cloud_msg).header.frame_id, (*cloud_msg).header.stamp , ros::Duration(5.0)); 
listener->transformPointCloud ("/marker", saved_cloud1, localized_cloud1);
```

throws:

```
[ INFO] [1462816855.501940141, 1462394890.300726653]: transformingPointCloud
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::ExtrapolationException'
  what():  Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1462394885.150079987, but only time 1462394885.320931978 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [marker]
```

How do I tell ROS to use a transform published after the pointcloud was assembled?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233966/tf2::extrapolationexception,-transforming-point-clouds-from-the-past-using-a-new-transform/) by [MWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/7271/mwrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can lookup the newest possible transform between two frames with `ros::Time(0)` instead of `(*cloud_msg).header.stamp`, as you have above.
However, that may not accurately reflect the position of the point cloud if your base has moved.

It looks like you're getting a point cloud from before the first tf is available. This may just be a startup condition that will go away after tfs are published and your node receives them. If that might be the case, you should consider waiting to process the point cloud or catching this exception and doing nothing until you receive some tfs.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0